# Value has an invalid format and must be of the form YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM

Tags: python, django, datetime, time, aggregate

I'm working with django 1.6 and I get error in the last line of my code:

```
start__gte=min_date, start__lte=max_date)
```

Here is error:

```
[U "'start__min' value has an invalid format and must be of the form YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM [: ss [.uuuuuuu]] [TZ]"
```

Here is my function:

```
def person_coming_events(person):
    active_seasons = Season.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    min_date, max_date = active_seasons.aggregate(Min('start'), Max('end'))
    production_ids = SeasonProduction.objects.filter(season__in=active_seasons).values_list('production_id', flat=True)
    return Activity.objects.filter(production_id__in=production_ids, cast__person=person,
                                   start__gte=min_date, start__lte=max_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

The *aggregation* returns a two item dictionary. Unpacking the dictionary like you did, only returns the dictionary keys to `min_date` and `max_date`; meaning they are assigned to strings `'start__min'` and `'end__max'`, which are not valid date values.

You should instead access the respective dictionary key and assign the date values to your variables:

```
agg = active_seasons.aggregate(Min('start'), Max('end'))
min_date, max_date = agg['start__min'], agg['end__max']
```

BTW, you should consider upgrading from Django1.6